# Eclipse: How to set MessageId at problems view

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

Using `org.eclipse.cdt.core` to parse my C code errors and warnings to log to my eclipse application.

After extending the `org.eclipse.cdt.core`, i get these 7 fields.

```
 - severity -> warning
 - eat-processed-line -> true
 - regex -> (.*): line (.*) warning : (#\d+) .*)
 - file-expr -> $1
 - line-expr -> $2
 - description-expr -> $0
 - variable-expr
```

How to set the `Message Id` (which is $3 in this case) with this regex pattern? What does 'variable-expr' specify for?

Is it possible to set Message Id with `org.eclipse.cdt.core`?

Comment: Not sure what you are mean by message id in this context. Can you expand on this. Presumably you are discussing extending org.eclipse.cdt.core.*ErrorParser*  (PS Have you read the contents of "Show extension point description" link in the plugin.xml editor?) Using the RegexErrorParser is optional, you can write any error parser you want by implementing IErrorParser

Comment: @JonahGraham my product has its own field for Message Id(an ID given to each wranings\errors from the compiler) which will be part of the description. My problem is, if I chose to mark that ID with the help of regex grouping, how do I get that?

Comment: You can have as many groups as you want, and IIRC you can make the description-expr something like `$3 (ID:$4)`

Comment: @JonahGraham I am thinking of using the unused field 'variable-expr' where i will set (ID=$3) and will parse the same thing.